# Less files not converted to css when publishing the project in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, less, dotless

My problem is am unable to compile .less files to .css using dotless in production server. I installed the dotless package using Nuget in Visual Studio 2010.
Its working fine locally. No css file is generated.

When i see the view source, i see the following in the head section of the page:-

```
<link href="/MyProjectFolder/Content/styles?v=" rel="stylesheet">
```

and there is no content displayed when i click on this above link as the file is not generated.

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue.

**Update 1: Mentioned the approach by which am calling the less files**

Am using the bundling of less files by using the following code in the BundleConfig.cs file as:-

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/common").Include("~/Content/common.less"));
```

and in my html page in the head section I call it using

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/common")
```

My common.less file also has reference to two other files, using import. So the common.less file would like:-

```
@import "variables.less";
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);

body{
 background-color: @body-bg;
}
```

..and so on

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how you are using dotless.  Are you referencing the less file directly in the page?  Or are you using bundling?  If so how?

Comment: Colin I am using the bundling approach to reference the less file. I have updated my question to show the code.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you are adding a bundle transformer to compile the LESS files.

Please see the documentation [here](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) under "LESS, CoffeeScript, SCSS, Sass Bundling."

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this is to remove dependency on `dotLess` and use free Visual Studio Extension https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler for precompilation of less to css (with and without minification).